# Generate random number in excel

Tags: excel

Would anyone mind telling me how to use the equation: P(n+1) = (5Pn + 13) mod 11 with p1=1 and generate the first 20 terms of the sequence of number by using excel?

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and we'll show you how to get on the right path.

Comment: [generate random number in Excel vba](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rnd.php)

Comment: Your sequence only has 5 terms. You're doing something wrong.

Comment: What does this have to do with random numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Put the value 1 in cell A1 then put `=MOD(5*A1 + 13, 11)` in cell A2 and copy the formula down through the first 20 rows.  The formula uses cell A1 as the first seed value to compute cell A2, then uses that to compute A3 and so on.

(Note: This is not very random.)

Comment: You beat me to it by 20 seconds. Well, all's fair in typing matches.